# How to hide button "Approve" in from view of odoo without coding?

Tags: odoo

Please, I need to hide the "Approve" button that is in the "Expense Reports to Approve" view without any code changes, I use odoo 11 and, the module I installed is hr_expense. Here is part of the code for this view:

```
<form string="Expense Reports" class="o_expense_sheet" modifiers="{}">
        <header modifiers="{}">
            <button name="approve_expense_sheets" states="submit" string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight o_expense_sheet_approve" modifiers="{'invisible':[['state','not in',['submit']]]}" options="{}"/>
            <button name="action_sheet_move_create" states="approve" string="Post Journal Entries" type="object" class="oe_highlight o_expense_sheet_post" modifiers="{'invisible':[['state','not in',['approve']]]}" options="{}"/>
            <button name="248" type="action" string="Register Payment" class="oe_highlight o_expense_sheet_pay" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'post')]}" context="{'default_amount': total_amount, 'partner_id': address_id}" modifiers="{'invisible':[['state','!=','post']]}" options="{}"/>
            <button name="reset_expense_sheets" states="cancel" string="Resubmit" type="object" modifiers="{'invisible':[['state','not in',['cancel']]]}" options="{}"/>
            <button name="247" states="submit,approve" context="{'hr_expense_refuse_model':'hr.expense.sheet'}" string="Refuse" type="action" modifiers="{'invisible':[['state','not in',['submit','approve']]]}" options="{}"/>
            <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,submit,approve,post,done" on_change="1" modifiers="{'readonly':true,'required':true}"/>
        </header>
        <sheet modifiers="{}">
            <div class="oe_button_box" modifiers="{}">
                <button name="action_get_attachment_view" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-book" type="object" modifiers="{}" options="{}">
                    <field name="attachment_number" widget="statinfo" string="Documents" modifiers="{'readonly':true}"/>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without any code changes"?

Comment: not make new group or coding...but use configuration of odoo

Comment: You could create a new group, but have to create an external identifier for that group too. Then you can use the group in the button (form view above) with `groups` attribute. And then you have to set that view to not updateable, or on app/module update this change will be overriden. Can you handle this solution? If yes i would write it down in more detail as answer.

Comment: you are right, i have did that and it work, but i should not use my own module created by me...but only use the features that already exist in odoo

Comment: My solution is fully working without a custom module. Why do you think you have to use your module?

Comment: but you have created new group, and i wish use only groups  that already exist in odoo

Comment: There is no module needed for a group creation. You could also use an existing group, but you have to decide carefully which one.

Comment: So How to  create new group?

Comment: Depends on the Odoo version, but normally under Settings/Users & Companies/Groups. In newer versions you need to activate the developer mode to see this menu.

Comment: "you need to activate the developer mode to see this menu"

Comment: Ok, what information for creation of this group: Application:?, Portail:?, ...Or  any choice i do is right?

Comment: Just try it out and learn something ;-)

Comment: How to create an external identifier for that group

Comment: You'll find the menu under Settings/Technical/Sequences & Identifiers/External Identifiers. Developer mode is needed to see the "Technical" menu. As "Module" enter either "__export__" or something that's not a real module. If you use a real module name, Odoo will delete your group on update of that module.

Comment: i can't find the id of group created ?

Comment: It's in the url when in the form (view) of that group

Comment: i put this id in groups attribute of button tag in xml file ?

Comment: Yes like `groups="__export__.my_new_group"` as example. Only user within this group should see the button, except the admin.

Comment: Remember to make this view not updateable! You can handle that in the external identifier of the view.

Comment: thanks you so much